# I'm trying to install chatify to my laravel 8 project but it looks like the css is not loading I followed all the steps but not sure what I'm missing

Tags: php, chat, laravel-8

I have been having issues installing chatify on my larval 8 project. it seems that chatify was installed, but when I go to localhost/chatify it looks like the CSS is not loading. I have been getting issues trying to run  php artisan migrate because it says the name is already in use but I am unsure if that could really cause this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "it seems" is pretty broad...

Answer (score 0):

Just all you need is to run the following command in cmd or vs code terminal:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=chatify-asset
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
npm install && npm run dev
```